# pymongo returns an SSL error when trying to connect to local Mongo instance

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, pymongo

I'm writing a small app that writes JSON files to a Mongo collection and then retrieves them based on a given input. I have my Mongo settings stored as a Pydantic model as follows in `settings.py`:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseSettings

__all__ = ["mongo_settings"]


class MongoSettings(BaseSettings):
    host: str = "mongodb://127.0.0.1"
    port: int = 27017
    minPoolSize: int = 10
    maxPoolSize: int = 10
    username: str = None
    password: str = None
    authSource: Optional[str] = ""
    tls: bool = True
    tlsAllowInvalidCertificates: bool = True

mongo_settings = MongoSettings()
```

these are used in a `Database` class with a method that returns a `MongoClient`:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from .settings import mongo_settings


class Database:
    client: MongoClient = None

    def get_database() -> MongoClient:
        client = MongoClient(**mongo_settings.dict())
        return client
```

I've written an (extremely) basic test to check that my app can connect to a locally running instance of Mongo:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from database.db import Database

def test_database_connection():

    mongo: MongoClient = Database.get_database()

    mongo.server_info()
```

However, this fails with the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 909, in _configured_socket
    sock = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host)
  File "/home/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/home/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/home/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1749, in _process_periodic_tasks
    self._topology.update_pool()
  File "/code/project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 438, in update_pool
    server._pool.remove_stale_sockets(pool_id)
  File "/code/project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1060, in remove_stale_sockets
    sock_info = self.connect()
  File "/code/project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1089, in connect
    sock = _configured_socket(self.address, self.opts)
  File "/code/project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 922, in _configured_socket
    _raise_connection_failure(address, exc, "SSL handshake failed: ")
  File "/code/project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 290, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise AutoReconnect(msg)
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: SSL handshake failed: 127.0.0.1:27017: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1108)
```

I've tried playing around with the `/etc/mongod.conf` file to see if that will solve the problem, with the `net` block currently looking like this:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    CAFile: "~/.ssl/ca.pem"
    PEMKeyFile: "~/.ssl/server.pem"
    PEMKeyPassword: 'XXXXXXXXX'
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
```

but this hasn't yielded any results. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here which is causing it to not work, does anybody have any insight as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with the code itself - the tilde shortcut in the `mongod.conf` file meant the certificates weren't being read properly. Swapping that out for an absolute path seems to have solved the problem

Comment: Tilde is a shell construct, so that would be expected behavior.